# Kaminari combine two collections and place heading in between

Tags: ruby, kaminari

I have a page with two collections of items.

```
def index 
  @collection1 = Model.collection1
  @collection2 = Model.collection2
end
```

I'm aware of how to combine them together to paginate with Kaminari, however I need to place a `<h1>collection 2</h1>` header before the items of `@collection2` starts (if any).

The page would be something like this:

```
..Item from collection 1..
..Item from collection 1..
..Item from collection 1..
<h1>collection 2</h1>
..Item from collection 2..
..Item from collection 2..
```

Im having a hard time figuring out a way to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following solution.

```
def index
  @collection1 = Model.collection1
  @collection2 = Model.collection2
  @collection1_paginated = @collection1.page(params[:page])
  @collection2_paginated = Kaminari.paginate_array(@collection1 + @collection2).page(params[:page])
  .padding(@collection1_paginated.size)
  .take(@collection1_paginated.limit_value - @collection1_paginated.size)
  @collection1_or_collection2 = Kaminari.paginate_array(@collection1 + @collection2).page(params[:page])
end
```

And in the views you can do:

```
= render partial: 'model', collection: @collection1_paginated
- display_collection_2_heading?
  h1 collection 2
= render partial: 'model', collection: @collection2_paginated

= paginate @collection1_or_collection2
```

To display the *Collection 2* heading create the following helper.

```
def display_collection_2_heading? 
  @collection1.present? && ((@collection1.count / @collection1_paginated.limit_value)+1) == @collection1_paginated.current_page
end
```

This helpers makes sure the heading only goes one only time after the last item from *@collection1*.